# deducting conservation of linear momentum in material media

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Good evening,

I'm  trying to deduce the continuity equation for the fields and particles momentum , something like

$\nabla \cdot (-\Pi) + \frac{\partial \vec{g}}{\partial t}=-f$

I should get that $\vec{g}=\frac{\vec{E} \times \vec{H}}{4\pi c}$, but I'm getting instead $\vec{g}=\frac{\vec{D} \times \vec{B}}{4\pi c}$

I have checked several times but I cannot find any mistake on my procedures (basically, expressing densities of charge/current in terms of the fields using Maxwell equations and replacing them in the force per unit volume formula (Lorentz force per unit volume)).

Are these two cross products equal somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equal. You have apparently stumbled upon the [Abraham-Minkowski debate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Minkowski_controversy), which has raged for a century (although the complexion has changed a bit in the last decade or so).  Enjoy!

Comment: Oh god, I thought it was a simple answer, rather than a very interesting one xD my professor just told me "I did it once and it gave me ExH so check it"... thank you!